# URL condition in Twig

Tags: theming, 8

I have a category `mysite/news` (the page created by the Views) and when I turn to the next page of this category - `mysite/news?page=1`, some text and image should not be displayed.

This code does not work

```
{% if url == 'mysite/news' %}
some text
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use 'in' operator to get around this issue. Try something like:

```
{% if 'mysite/news' in url %}

some text

{% endif %}
```